# Firebase OnChildAdded() event is producing doubles in the scrollview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just started to learn Firebase for android a couple of weeks ago, and now I am creating a very basic chat application.

My problem occurs when I press the home button and then go back to the app. I think it calls the `OnChildAdded()` event again, and so it produces doubles. I don't know how to fix this. I'll be grateful if anyone could help me out.

This is the part where I am having trouble:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //messageText.append(username + ": " + messageReceived + " \n");
            Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            String newmsg = null, theusername = null;
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                newmsg = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
                theusername = (String)  ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();

            }
            messageText.append(theusername + ": " + newmsg + " \n");
            scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            },200);
        }
```

Here is a picture of the emulator and the structure of my firebase console:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If `onChildAdded()` is being called multiple times for the same child, it is *very* likely that you have multiple listeners attached. You'll need to [detach the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#detach_listeners) when your activity becomes inactive.

```
 // if you attach like this
 var listener = ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

 // later detach the listener with
 ref.removeEventListener(listener);
```

The best place to detach the listener depends on where you attached it. It is usually best to think of the pairs: `onCreate()`->`onDestroy()`, `onStart()`->`onStop()`, `onResume()`->`onPause()`.

Comment: i have these onChildEvents in the onStart() method only, but let me try your method

Comment: Sorry sir i am unable to understand what you said can you please elaborate it more? Code wise ? Thank you.

Comment: No one here to help ? :(